# What is an adjective that describes an increase in clarity of a telescope?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

If I bought a new telescope, what would be the best adjective in English to describe how much more precisely I can see things in the sky using this new telescope as opposed to the old one?

1. Wow! This new telescope is so much **more precise**!
2. Wow! This new telescope is so much **clearer**!
3. Wow! This new telescope is so much **more distinctive**!
4. Wow! This new telescope is so much **better in vision**!
5. ?

Comment: Photographers use the word "sharper" to describe clarity of a photograph. Try that on for size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are abstracting your *telescope* to include properties of the telescope.  Which is fine for most situations.  Your first sentence sounds fine and will be understood in most situations.

Saying your telescope is more precise, however, leaves your statement open to interpretation.  Is it more precise in that you have more control over its movement as you scan the sky?

If you want to talk about an increase in the resolution of your telescope, it would be clearer if you talk about your *telescope's resolution*, not merely your telescope.

Clarity, distinction, and precision would all be considered part of the telescope's *resolution*.  That being the case I would mention that I am talking about the telescope's resolution in my sentence.

> This new telescope's resolution is much higher/better.

Answer (score 1):

None of your suggestions work very well to my ears as you are describing the telescope when what you really want to do is to describe the operation of the telescope. I would suggest

> This new telescope gives a much sharper image
> This new telescope gives a much clearer image

Comment: But doesn't it sound a bit too wordy for a casual conversation, which would have those example phrases in my question?

Answer (score -1):

1 is ok, but not great.

2 ("clearer") is the best.

3 and 4 don't work.